# Service Fabric with nginx and .NET core services

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I'm setting up a Service Fabric application which contains:

- an Nginx instance as frontend (single instance, port 80)
- some applications written with Asp.net core (1 website, some API services) (multiple instances, dynamic port)
- a Gateway service for address resolution (single instance, port 8081)

For nginx, I'm using a solution available as [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NginxPoC/).
The gateway and, in general, the example to run .NET core app have been taken [here](https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting)

It is suggested by the .NET core team itself to host applications behind a *real* web server liken **nginx**.
Therefore I'd like to deploy my Service Fabric application with an instance of **nginx** as entry point, which redirects to the Gateway service, which will do the service resolution for the replicated stateless services.

My question is about the address that I need to use in the nginx.conf to point to the Gateway address. While trying locally, I can use the local address **127.0.0.1** and it works as expected, but **what happens if on a real cluster my Nginx and Gateway instances are deployed to different machines**?

This is my application manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="SFApplicationType" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="NginxPoC_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="1" />
    <Parameter Name="Gateway_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="1" />
  </Parameters>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="NginxPoCPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <Policies>
      <RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="Admin" EntryPointType="All" />
    </Policies>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="Gateway" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="NginxPoC">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="NginxPoCType" InstanceCount="[NginxPoC_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
    <Service Name="Gateway">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="GatewayType" InstanceCount="[Gateway_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
  <Principals>
    <Users>
      <User Name="Admin">
        <MemberOf>
          <SystemGroup Name="Administrators" />
        </MemberOf>
      </User>
    </Users>
  </Principals>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

and this is my current nginx.conf file:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        }
}
```

**Update 2016-10-09**

As requested in the discussion, I've created a test project [here](https://github.com/fleed/servicefabric-advanced). Every contribute to the project is welcome.

Comment: Create question, but if you are creating a gateway for service resolution - why is it again that you need nginx infront of that since that also is just a proxy? I have experienced with the same idea but choose not to have nginx infront, so I am curious.

Comment: The .NET core team suggests having IIS or nginx in front of Kestrel.
Additionally, I'll get benefits like gzip, http2, etc.

Comment: Let us know if these suggestions are from public links. It makes sense, and maybe there are other things worth reading from these suggestions.

Comment: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html?highlight=kestrel#kestrel
Quote: Kestrel is designed to be run behind a proxy (for example IIS or Nginx) and should not be deployed directly facing the Internet.

And here some tips: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/aspnetmonsters/ASPNET-Monsters-Episode-51-An-Intro-to-Nginx-for-Kestrel

Comment: I coded a proxy gateway to avoid using nginx, but based on this I properly will use nginx. But then using nginx i dont see why you also want gateway project. Cant you just tell nginx to forward to the services?

Comment: Actually, having both of them looks weird.
Anyway I see it necessary if you have 5 nodes and you want to deploy the web application to only 3 of them. In such case, nginx will redirect to the gateway, which will find an app on one of the available nodes.

Comment: I am working on a project, a few weeks from being able to make it public. Here I am wrapping Nginx in a stateless service running on all nodes and is exposed on public port. Then my microservices will register them self against the wrapper service which will then reconfigure nginx. I imagine that i can then tell nginx where the 3 of 5 nodes are. (still playing with the concept)

Comment: I guess it's possible, but it would require some LUA scripting.
I'm interested in the results, hope you will share yours after playing with it!

Comment: nginx probably cannot do service resolution, which I guess would then be the primary concern of the gateway service (or reverse proxy could be used). Building service resolution and registration into nginx I really do not see why. Regarding Kestrel, it is not yet ready to face the Internet, but will eventually be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f you deploy the nginx and gateway service to all nodes (InstanceCount = -1) you should be good. If the gateway service is down on one node, you would of course not be able to forward the request from nginx to a gateway service on another node. For this, you need the nginx service to look-up the gateway service.

You can get the service endpoint address for the gateway using a REST call: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn707638.aspx

Comment: I've tried it, setting InstanceCount to -1 and using 127.0.0.1 as address for redirect in nginx config (specifying the port for the service), assuming that the service is available on every node.
Unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: HAve you looked at this blog, describing the package usage: http://haishibai.blogspot.com/2016/08/sharing-your-service-fabric-services-as.html

Comment: yes, I'm using that package.
I've found the problem: in the startup of the .net core application I was only configuring the endpoint url. As soon as I've added the local address (and port), everything worked.
The answer is correct.

Comment: Great - good to know :-) Are you willing to share the project in GitHub or somewhere else as an example for others to look at?

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to a test solution on GitHub.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/ could be another option. Still, not sure if it is "enough" in front of .NET core applications